# What does the pre shape, and EQ In/Out buttons do on my guitar?

Tags: guitar, terminology, guitar-effects

I just bought a second hand ovation celebrity and I was wondering what some of its buttons do. Do they change the sound (distortion/loudness)? If not what do they do?

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 1):

Eq is equaliser. A sophisticated tone control split into several frequency bands. The pre shape is a preset shaping of tone that Ovation hope players will like and use. The eq in/out actually switches the equaliser on/off. So, with the eq set to what you want for a particular sound, instantly there are options.